# Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding

Tags: ssis

while runnig the ssis package i'm calling sp in the ADO.net source,but getting this error
Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.I have set the command timeout to 0(infinite time),but still getting the error.The sp is working fine in sql server and taking approx 31 seconds for executing it,but in ssis its throwing error..please help me on this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/eeff8fe6-620d-425e-b939-08c2cb66e3e2).  It turns out you may see a timeout error when it's really a truncation error.  Also, you can extend the client timeout, but still hit a server timeout.  Extending the server timeout uses syntax like `EXEC sp_configure 'remote query timeout', 6000`

Answer (score 2):

Check out this [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/783291/ssis-package-fails-to-start-application-lock-timeout-in-ssisdb-catalog-create-execution#tabs) - there is a sp in the SSISDB database in SQL Server 2012 causing packages to time out before they start running.  I had error message "Failed to execute IS server package because of error 0x80131904" and "Description: The operation failed because the execution timed out" when calling multiple (more than 10) packages from my scheduling tool via DTExec.  Please vote for the issue on the connect site so that MS can release an official fix.

Answer (score 2):

Today, I was experiencing the same error while using the ADO Net Source, my sp works fine on the SSMS, but fails in the package, while In the package, it errors our with a long laundry list of errors, but basically it is timing out.

Solution is Right click on the **ADO Net Source** - Show Advanced Editor - Component Properties - Custom Properties - **CommandTimeout - Increase the time here**

Comment: it's solved my problem after a long search!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in SSAS.

The way I sorted this out was extending the client and server time out settings.
you can see more details in the link below:

[routine to backup ssas databases fails with: The XML for Analysis request timed out before it was completed](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/81928/routine-to-backup-ssas-databases-fails-with-the-xml-for-analysis-request-timed/82485#82485)